# Warning 325: Nested class not currently supported (Proxy ignored)

Tags: c++, tcl, swig

I am getting the following Warning while running the swig interface file
Warning 325: Nested class not currently supported (Proxy ignored).
**I was able to suppress the warning**. But I need the nested class for computation

Below is the Interface file(example.i)

```
%module example
%{
#include "Rinside.h"
#include "Rinsidecommon.h"
#include "Callbacks.h"
%}
/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "Rinside.h"
%include "Rinsidecommon.h"
%include "Callbacks.h"
```

While executing the interface file. The following are the warnings

```
C:\swigwin-3.0.12\Examples\r\Rinside>swig -tcl -c++ example.i
Rinside.h(70) : Warning 325: Nested class not currently supported (Proxy ignored)
Rinside.h(91) : Warning 503: Can't wrap 'operator []' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
```

**I am trying to calling RInside from Tcl. First, my C code should be able to take arguments, call RInside by passing  those arguments, and print the results of RInside execution**.

Below is my nested class in Rinside.h File.
How can I include the nested class in the interface file??
I am relatively new to swig

```
    class Proxy {
public:
    Proxy(SEXP xx): x(xx) { };

    template <typename T>
    operator T() {
        return ::Rcpp::as<T>(x);
    }
private:
    Rcpp::RObject x;
};
```

Can some one please provide me a skeleton or some part of the code. It will be helpful for me

I am getting the following errors while wrapping the cpp code

```
rinside_sample0_wrap.cxx: In function 'int _wrap_RInside_parseEval__SWIG_1(ClientData, Tcl_Interp*, int, Tcl_Obj* const*)':\
rinside_sample0_wrap.cxx:1906:18: error: no matching function for call to 'RInside::Proxy::Proxy()'
In file included from rinside_sample0_wrap.cxx:1700:0:
Rinside.h:61:6: note: candidate: RInside::Proxy::Proxy(SEXP)
Proxy(SEXP xx): x(xx) { };
Rinside.h:61:6: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Show us a minimal complete example interface that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Edited Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SWIG Documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nested_classes)…

> **Compatibility Note:** Prior to SWIG-3.0.0, there was limited nested class support. Nested classes were treated as opaque pointers. However, there was a workaround for nested class support in these older versions requiring the user to replicate the nested class in the global scope, adding in a typedef for the nested class in the global scope and using the "nestedworkaround" feature on the nested class. This resulted in approximately the same behaviour as the "flatnested" feature. With proper nested class support now available in SWIG-3.0.0, this feature has been deprecated and no longer works requiring code changes.

You therefore ought to use 3.0 or later for support for nested classes. That will allow you to avoid needing to suppress anything, and might fix your other issues too.

Comment: But I have been using swig - 3.0.12 version. I still don't understand why I am getting the warning and the error

Comment: In that case, I don't know what is up. It sounds like some basic assumption is being violated. Contact the SWIG authors/maintainers for help...

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue with python. When i used `3.0.12` with a nested class i would just see the warning:

`Warning 325: Nested class not currently supported (Foo ignored)`

So i used the following feature:

```
   %module test
   %feature("flatnested", "1");

   %rename (Bar_Foo) Bar::Foo;
   class Foo {};
   class Bar {
    public:
    class Foo {};
   };
```

Actually in my problem I disabled the feature again after the specific case where i needed it (as it caused trouble with enum classes).